# Determinant of diagonal matrix D

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, diagonalization

Suppose $A$ is $n\times n$ and $P^{-1}AP = D$ for some invertible $P$. Does $\det(A) = \det(D)$?

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes (just naively guessing and checking), but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Yes it follows from taking determinant of both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

det has the following property: $$\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$$ 
So $$\det(D) = \det(P^{-1}AP) = \det(P^{-1})\det(A)\det(P) = (\det(P))^{-1}\det(A)\det(P) = \det(A)$$

$$1 = \det(\textrm{Id}) = \det(P^{-1}P) = \det(P^{-1})\det(P)$$

and so

$$\frac{1}{\det(P)} = \det(P^{-1})$$

Answer (score 1):

If we are in some field $F$, the following is true: Using the product rule and $\det P\neq 0$ since it has an inverse, we get

$$\det D=(\det P)^{-1}\det A\det P=\det A.$$

Answer (score 0):

The two matrices are [similar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity), and thus their determinant is the same.